# How to get ordered items associated with tracking numbers?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, shipment, shipment-tracking

How I can get collection of items associated to that particular tracking numbers for each shipment of order using order id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to keep in mind that each order can have **multiple shipments** and that each shipment can have **multiple tracking numbers** with **multiple products**.

**Solution 1**

After looking at `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php` you see that there are two methods of interest:

- `getAllItems()` and
- `getAllTracks()`

Which you can then use on your `$order` object

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($your_order_id);
$shipment_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
            ->setOrderFilter($order)
            ->load();
foreach($shipment_collection as $shipment){
    echo "Tracking number(s) for shipment:<br/>";
    foreach($shipment->getAllTracks() as $tracking_number){
        echo $tracking_number->getNumber() . "<br/>";
    }
    echo "Product(s) on shipment:<br/>";
    foreach ($shipment->getAllItems() as $product){
        echo $product->getName() . "<br/>";
    }
}
```

**Solution 2 - Direct SQL Statements**

The reason I'm including this is because I always find it very useful to check the database structure when I'm struggling with something. After a quick glance at the database, you see some notable tables namely:

- `sales_flat_shipment`,
- `sales_flat_shipment_item` and
- `sales_flat_shipment_track`

Immediately with these tables in mind, you know pretty much exactly how to find what you are looking for by simply looking at their column names.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($your_order_id);
$sales_flat_shipment = $this->_getTableName('sales_flat_shipment');
$sales_flat_shipment_track = $this->_getTableName('sales_flat_shipment_track');
$sales_flat_shipment_item = $this->_getTableName('sales_flat_shipment_item');
$connection = $this->_getConnection('core_read');
$sql = 'SELECT entity_id FROM ' . $sales_flat_shipment . ' WHERE order_id = ?';
$shipments = $connection->fetchAll($sql, $your_order_id);
foreach($shipments as $shipment){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $sales_flat_shipment_track . ' WHERE parent_id = ?';
    $tracking = $connection->fetchAll($sql, $shipment['entity_id']);
    echo "Tracking number(s) for the order:<br/>";
    foreach ($tracking as $track){
        echo $track['track_number'] . "<br/>";
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' . $sales_flat_shipment_item . ' WHERE parent_id = ?';
    $items = $connection->fetchAll($sql, $shipment['entity_id']);
    echo "Product(s) on shipment:<br/>";
    foreach ($items as $item){
        echo $item['name'] . "<br/>";
    }
}

public function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

public function _getTableName($tableName){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @moose, really appreciate it. Using your suggestions I definitely get item and tracking collection of shipment.  But What I am trying to ask is, How I will get item collection of particular tracking code? Say One shipment has 3 items and have two tracking numbers. One tracking number has 2 items and another one has 1 item. So how I can find which SKU belongs to which tracking number?

Comment: @ganesh, Magento doensn't assign tracking numbers to products, but to shipments. As I mentioned, you can have multiple tracking numbers PER shipment, but Magento does not assign those tracking numbers to the products on order, but to the shipment as a whole.

Comment: To overcome this issue I find a way around. Using carrier API (In my case FedEx, Aramex) check which sku belong to that particular tracking number and then compare it to order collection. This solution will defer case by case.