# How to get the products associated with shipment Id?

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sales-order, shipment, shipment-tracking

I've looked at

[How to get ordered items associated with tracking numbers?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/15083/how-to-get-ordered-items-associated-with-tracking-numbers)

[How to Access Shipment from Order ID and product ID?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/87604/how-to-access-shipment-from-order-id-and-product-id)

[How to get the shipment number of an order item?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56452/how-to-get-the-shipment-number-of-an-order-item)

[Create part shipment and check if item has been shipped](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/7213/create-part-shipment-and-check-if-item-has-been-shipped)

None have worked for what I'm trying to do.

I have the shipment ID in a variable `$shipid`. Is there anyway to get the products that go with the shipment ID?

I have my figures crossed!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to load the shipment:

```
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->load($shipid);
```

If you're using the increment id, you'll have to use:

```
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment')->loadByIncrementId($shipid);
```

Once you have the shipment loaded, you can retrieve the items collection:

```
$itemsCollection = $shipment->getItemsCollection();
```

Finally to get the product from the items you can loop through the item collections:

```
foreach($itemsCollection as $item)
{
    $_product = $item->getProduct();
}
```

Comment: I'm working on it. Let you know

Comment: I get an error when I echo $_product->getName(); returns null.  $array = array($_product);print_r(array_values($array)); returns Array ( [0] => ). But  $array = array($item);print_r(array_values($array)); returns [name] => Chess Set [sku] => 100022 in the array

Comment: @Freejoy in that case you can do `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getSku(),'sku');` to load your product

Comment: I just got it! After two days. I changed $item->getProduct(); to $item->getName(); then echo $_product; And it worked.Thanks You were so close I mark it as correct

Comment: @Freejoy I'm glad we got it working :)

Answer (score 1):

change $item->getProduct(); To  $item->getData();